# read from a pipe: How to handle the return values in c?

Tags: c, pipe, return-value

I'm writing a program to read from a pipe and I want to know what is the correct way of handling the return values. According to the read man page,

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right  now  (maybe  because  we were  close  to  end-of-file,  or  because  we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

I'm worried about the case where it may read only half of the data. Also, what is the correct way to handle the case when the return value is zero?

Here is my sample code.

```
struct day
{
        int date;
        int month;
};

while(1)
{
        ret = select(maxfd+1, &read_fd, NULL, &exc_fd,NULL);
        if(ret < 0)
        {
                perror("select");
                continue;
        }
        if(FD_ISSET(pipefd[0], &read_fd))
        {
                struct day new_data;
                if((ret = read(pipefd[0], &new_data, sizeof(struct day)))!= sizeof(struct day))
                {
                        if(ret < 0)
                        {
                                perror("read from pipe");
                                continue;
                        }
                        else if(ret == 0)
                        {
                                /*how to handle?*/
                        }
                        else
                        /* truncated read. How to handle?*/
                }
        }
        ...
}
```

I believe read() cannot read more data than the size specified. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Please help me with the handling of return value of read.

Comment: Please post a working example. Your code will not compile. Check the `if((ret= pipefd` line.

Comment: You are right in worrying about partial `read`-s; you definitely should buffer and handle these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `read` you request for a given amount of data, but nothing can guarantee you that there is as much available data to read as you requested. For example, you may encounter the end of file, or the writer part didn't write too much data in your pipe. So `read` returns you what was effectively read, aka *the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file)*.

If `read` returns a strictly positive number, it's clear.

If `read` returns 0, then that means end of file. For a regular file that means that you are currently at the end of the file. For a pipe this means that the pipe is empty **and** that no single byte will ever be written to. For pipes that means that you already read all data and that there is no more writer on the other end (so that no more byte will be written), so you can then close the now unuseful pipe.

If `read` returns -1 this means that an *error* happened, and you must consult `errno` variable to determine the cause of the trouble.

So, a general schema could be something like:

```
n = read(descriptor,buffer,size);
if (n==0) { // EOF
  close(descriptor);
} else if (n==-1) { // error
  switch(errno) { // consult documentations for possible errors
    case EAGAIN: // blahblah
  }
} else { // available data
  // exploit data from buffer[0] to buffer[n-1] (included)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If read returns 0, then your process has read all of the data that will come from that file descriptor.  Take it out of read_fd and if it was the maxfd reset maxfd to the newest max.  Depending on what your process is doing, you might have other cleanup to do as well. If you get a short read, then either process the data you've received or discard it or store it until you get all the data and can process it.

It's hard to give more specific answers to a very general question.